# L.append(x) vs L[len(L):len(L)] = [x]

Tags: python, list

In Python, is there a difference (say, in performance) between writing

```
L.append(x)
```

and

```
L[len(L):len(L)] = [x]
```

where `L` is a list? If there is, what is it caused by?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do the second one in python.

Comment: did you try the latter? It could cause `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Comment: Trying this before asking would have saved Stackoverflow some database space :P

Comment: Sorry! Typo! I actually meant something slightly different (see edit)!

Comment: RE the edit: Yes, there's still a difference: The two do different things and the second only works for iterable `x`. Or did you mean to compare it to `L.extend(x)`?

Comment: In what way do they do different things?

Comment: This can easily be found out by trying it ;-) For example, start with `L = []` and use `1` and `[1]` for `x`.

Comment: Downvote removed after typo fix. :)

Comment: Do you mean `L[len(L):]=[x]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from `append` method, you could append elements to list using `insert`, I'm guessing that's what you are pointing at:

```
In [115]: l=[1,]

In [116]: l.insert(len(l), 11)

In [117]: l
Out[117]: [1, 11]
```

**l.append(x) vs. l.insert(len(l), x):**

```
In [166]: %timeit -n1000    l=[1]; l.append(11)
1000 loops, best of 3: 936 ns per loop

In [167]: %timeit -n1000    l=[1]; l.insert(len(l), 11)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 us per loop
```

It's obvious that method `append` is better.

and then **L.append(x) vs L[len(L):len(L)] = [x]**:

or `L[len(L):]=[x]`

```
In [145]: %timeit -n1000        l=[1]; l.append(123);
1000 loops, best of 3: 878 ns per loop

In [146]: %timeit -n1000        l=[1]; l[len(l):]=[123]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.24 us per loop

In [147]: %timeit -n1000        l=[1]; l[len(l):len(l)]=[123]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 us per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference on my system...

```
In [22]: f = (4,)

In [21]: %timeit l = [1,2,3]; l.append(4)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 265 ns per loop

In [23]: %timeit l = [1,2,3]; l.append(f)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 266 ns per loop

In [24]: %timeit l = [1,2,3]; l.extend(f)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 270 ns per loop

In [25]: %timeit l = [1,2,3]; l[4:] = f
1000000 loops, best of 3: 260 ns per loop
```

This means that in an apples-to-apples comparison, they are the same (above differences are probably less than random error).

However, anything extra (such as having to calculate len in that version) may skew the results for some particular implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As always, performance testing has pitfalls.  But in your example:

`x` need not be an iterable, you are *wrapping* it in an iterable.  This obviously is an extra step that incurs a performance penalty.

Performing `len(L)` is not free, it takes a non-zero amount of time.  This also incurs a performance penalty.

Some quick testing bears this out:

```
def f():
    a = []
    for i in range(10000):
        a.append(0)


def g():
    a = []
    for i in range(10000):
        a[len(a):len(a)] = [0]


%timeit f()
1000 loops, best of 3: 683 us per loop

%timeit g()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.4 ms per loop
```

Now one non-obvious "optimization" you can do to remove the `len(L)` effect is use a constant slice that is higher than the length of your list will ever get.  Extended slicing never throws an `IndexError`, even if you're waaaaay off the end of the iterable.  So let's do that.

```
def h():
    a = []
    for i in range(10000):
        a[11111:11111] = [0]


%timeit h()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.45 ms per loop
```

So as suspected, both wrapping your `x` in an iterable and calling `len` have small but tangible performance penalties.

---

And, of course, doing `li[len(li):len(li)]` is UGLY.  That's the biggest performance penalty: the time it takes my brain to figure out what the heck it just looked at.  :-)